# In h5py file upload, what is the difference between np.array(file[key][:]) and np.array(file[key])

Tags: python, python-3.x, h5py

I am currently playing around h5py file extract. When I run the script below, it seems to output the same result. Anyone knows the difference?

```
train_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/train_happy.h5', "r")
train_set_x_orig1 = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:])

train_set_x_orig2 = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"])
```

Thanks for anyone providing the input!

Comment: I always found `dataset[:]` optimal (with no `np.array` wrapper), but I have no evidence to support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sample file from some other SO question

```
In [183]: f = h5py.File('temp.h5','r')
In [184]: list(f.keys())
Out[184]: ['db1', 'db2', 'db3', 'db4', 'temp']
```

Simply asking for the key returns a `Dataset`  (a dictionary like operation)

```
In [185]: x = f['db1']
In [186]: type(x)
Out[186]: h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset
In [187]: x
Out[187]: <HDF5 dataset "db1": shape (5,), type "|V4">
```

Adding the `[:]` (or some other indexing) is enough to load the data into an array:

```
In [188]: y = f['db1'][:]
In [189]: type(y)
Out[189]: numpy.ndarray
In [190]: y
Out[190]: array([('a',), ('ab',), ('',), ('',), ('',)], dtype=[('str', 'O')])
```

No need for a further `np.array` wrapper.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

`value` attribute also works (I'm not sure where this is documented):

```
In [191]: x.value
Out[191]: array([('a',), ('ab',), ('',), ('',), ('',)], dtype=[('str', 'O')])
```

The `array` wrapper works:

```
In [192]: np.array(x)
Out[192]: array([('a',), ('ab',), ('',), ('',), ('',)], dtype=[('str', 'O')])
```

A quick set of `timeits` doesn't show any difference.

But in the release notes:

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.1.html#dataset-value-property-is-now-deprecated

> The property *Dataset.value*, which dates back to h5py 1.0, is deprecated and will be removed in a later release. This property dumps the entire dataset into a NumPy array. Code using .value should be updated to use NumPy indexing, using *mydataset[...]* or *mydataset[()]* as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive explain. So it seems there are more than two methods to transfer it into array. And they all do the same things.

Comment: In h5py 2.7.1, `data[...]` and `data.value` are both `numpy.ndarray` s;
in h5netcdf 0.5.1, `data[...]` is an ndarray, but there's no `data.value`.
Why not `.values` as in pandas and xarray ? a foolish consistency ...
(There's a tiny test case, ncgen test.cdl | read-nc.py, under gist.github.com/denis-bz .)

Comment: @denis, Deprecation of `.value` goes back to 2.1, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.1.html#dataset-value-property-is-now-deprecated.  Consistency of `h5py` with `numpy` makes sense, but I don't think it needs to match `pandas`.  `pandas` prefers to use `PyTables` and `HDFStore`.